# Django admin inline auto creates multiple fields on admin panel

Tags: python, django

I have a `TicketMessage` model that contains a foreign key to `Ticket`.
I wanted to have my `TicketMessage` **message** field appear on my `Ticket` admin panel as an inline.

I did succeeded in doing so however as shown in the image below for some reason by default it creates three message fields instead of one.

Would like to know how to make it so it shows only one **message** by default and the reason why this happens in the first place.

*TicketMessage* model

```py
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

from painless.models import TimeStampMixin

class TicketMessage(TimeStampMixin):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Ticket Message"),
        verbose_name_plural = ("Ticket Messages")

  
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(
        "Ticket",
        default=False,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name="ticket_message",
        help_text="Lorem ipsum"
    )

    message = models.TextField(
        _("message"),
        max_length=500,
        help_text="Lorem ipsum",
    )


    def __str__(self):
        return f"Ticket subject: {self.ticket}"

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Ticket subject: {self.ticket}"
```

*Ticket admin*

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from desk.models import (
    Ticket,
    TicketMessage
)


class TicketMessageInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = TicketMessage


@admin.register(Ticket)
class TicketAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = (
        'subject',
        'status_choices',
        'priority_choices',
        'is_read',
        'is_important',
        'is_archive',
    )

    list_filter = (
        'is_read',
        'is_important',
        'is_archive',
        'status_choices',
    )

    inlines = (
        TicketMessageInline,
    )

    filter_horizontal = (
        "tags",
    )

    
    fieldsets = (
        (_("Primary Informations"), {
            'fields': (
                'subject',
                'message',
                'status_choices',
                'priority_choices',
            )
        }),

        (_("Options"), {
            'fields': (
                'is_important',
                'is_archive',
                'is_read',
                'is_duplicated',
            )
        }),

        
        (_("Others"), {
            'fields': (
                'department',
                'resolved_at',
            )
        }),

        
        (_("Tags"), {
            'fields': (
                'tags',
            )
        }),
    )
```

*bug image*
[Bug imag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrOyU.png)

## Solution

As @Mojtaba pointed out, adding `extra = 1` fixes the issue

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from desk.models import (
    Ticket,
    TicketMessage
)


class TicketMessageInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = TicketMessage
    extra = 1


@admin.register(Ticket)
class TicketAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = (
        'subject',
        'status_choices',
        'priority_choices',
        'is_read',
        'is_important',
        'is_archive',
    )

    list_filter = (
        'is_read',
        'is_important',
        'is_archive',
        'status_choices',
    )

    inlines = (
        TicketMessageInline,
    )

    filter_horizontal = (
        "tags",
    )


    fieldsets = (
        (_("Primary Informations"), {
            'fields': (
                'subject',
                'message',
                'status_choices',
                'priority_choices',
            )
        }),

        (_("Options"), {
            'fields': (
                'is_important',
                'is_archive',
                'is_read',
                'is_duplicated',
            )
        }),


        (_("Others"), {
            'fields': (
                'department',
                'resolved_at',
            )
        }),


        (_("Tags"), {
            'fields': (
                'tags',
            )
        }),
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your inline use

```
extra = 1
```

this variable show how many empty inlines should be shown in admin panel.